# Can we use the Wicket:id to make CSS?

Tags: java, html, css, wicket, styling

is it possible to use the wicket:id of some element/component for CSS styling instead of "class"?

for example:

```
.tooltipster-arrow span, .column-shifter {
    display: block;
    width: 0; 
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

and i have in html code something like:

```
<body>
    <wicket:panel>
        <div wicket:id="column-shifter"></div>
    </wicket:panel>
</body>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not possible, as the browser will look for the `class` attribute when processing CSS. Furthermore, Wicket markup is removed in [deployment mode](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/How+to+remove+wicket+markup+from+output), so the `wicket:id` attribute should not be present in the final HTML (as it would reveal internal data of your application).

You could use an [AttributeModifier](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/AttributeModifier.html) to add the ID of your component as class attribute:

`myComponent.add(new AttributeModifier("class", myComponent.getId()));`

Answer (score 3):

You can just add a class="column-shifter" to the markup, like this:

```
<div wicket:id="column-shifter" class="column-shifter"></div>
```